# Is it possible to eliminate data loss with Redis?

Tags: redis

I understand Redis AOF and RDB persistence options and have read the doc (maybe not thoroughly). What I want to ask is this: is it possible to eliminate the possibility of data loss with Redis?

Setting `appendfsync` to `always` seems to be the closest solution. However, there is stil the possibility that Redis crashes just after responding to the client with "OK" and before persisting the data to disk. There would be no way for the client to know that the data is lost, which will result in inconsistency.

As far as I'm concerned, an option to make Redis respond after fsync should resolve the issue (or maybe an additional WAITFSYNC command). Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

i think for now the safest option is to add `appendonly yes` in your redis config.
if you are using version 1.1 or greater one.

`appendfsync always` is slowest among them. if you are okay with that then sure you can use it. but if you care about your DB's performance use `appendfsync everysec`.

The append-only file is a fully-durable strategy for `Redis`. every time Redis receives a command that changes the dataset (e.g. SET) it will append it to the AOF. When you restart Redis it will re-play the AOF to rebuild the state.

[details](https://redis.io/topics/persistence)

Answer (score 0):

We are using the combination of WAIT command and appendfsync: always. With WAIT command client receives the response only when it is synchronized to replicas. When we were talking with people from Redis, we concluded that this is safe enough for real world application, but that in academic terms we can't claim that we have strong consistency. This is a payment application in which it is not acceptable to lose any data, so we are willingly sacrificing performance.